# Convert uint8 to int64 in python

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I have a variable which is an uint8 type (it has just two values, 0 and 1), and I want to replace the zeros with -1. Do I have first to transform this variable to int64 (or any integer data type that allows negative numbers)? If so, how could I achieve it?

Comment: can you set it to 255 ?

Comment: what do you mean you have an `uint8`, are you using ctypes or numpy?

Comment: Python has no different integer types, so I’m not sure what kind of thing you are referring to. You should show some code of what you are doing.

Comment: I have just tried to replace 0 with -1, but it replaced it with 255

Comment: I'm using numpy

Comment: If you do `np.where(whatever == 0, -1, whatever)` you'll get a new array automatically promoted to `int16`...

Comment: Do you physically need to store -1 though? If 0 is effectively -1, it seems a bit of a waste to double the storage required for what's effectively a boolean array

Comment: Numpy objects (like your scalar) have a `astype` method, where you can put `np.int64` as the argument. Otherwise, overflow will occur on leaving the range, yes.

Comment: just a comment, if you have only 3 possible values (-1, 0, 1) and want to be memory-sparse, why don't you use just 2 booleans (which could be equivalent to int4, except the smallest int to my knowledge is int8) ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need int64. int8 should make it. to convert uint8 into int8 :

```
import numpy as np
x = np.uint8(-1) # -1 does not exist in this coding, this is just a test
x
> 255
np.int8(x)
> -1 # eureka
```